# Webform buttons displaying blank page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

The bug I'm trying to solve is that the buttons on my .aspx page that correspond to methods in the .vb file all return a blank page without actually getting to the vb code (no breakpoints I've put on these methods get triggered). There is no redirect as the URL doesn't change it simply registers the button click and then its handler gives a blank page. I thought at first that this would have something to do with doPostBack but even after putting "CausesValidation="false" " this still continues. I've recreated the button in the designer window just to be extra sure that the button points to code and the program knows it but still no luck.

Here is what the button itself looks like:

`<asp:Button ID="btnFreshTest" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" Text="Save User" ClientIDMode="Static" width="100px" ToolTip="Save changes" Height="35px" />`

Here is what the visual basic method code looks like, yes its simple but this is for a test:

```
Protected Sub btnFreshTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFreshTest.Click
        Dim testString2 As String = "abc"
    End Sub
```

Even if you don't have a solution given the lack of information, if you have any pointers that I could use like places to look for an error or somewhere to put a breakpoint with chrome tools, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, so while looking at the button in the designer if you double click on the button, it should jump you to code behind - does this result in a brand new code event stub? If yes, then move your above test code to that new stub - delete old one, and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we drop this into a page:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFreshTest" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"
Text="Save User" ClientIDMode="Static" 
width="100px" ToolTip="Save changes" Height="35px" />
```

So we see this:

[image]

Now do NOT JUST TYPE in the event stub - double click on the button above, and you now have this:

```
Protected Sub btnFreshTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFreshTest.Click

    Dim testString2 As String = "abc"

    Console.WriteLine("Value of test string = " & testString2)


End Sub
```

And when we run, then we get this:

[image]

So, you may well have messed up the event, but if you JUST drop in that button (say a cut + paste from example code), then the event stub will not automatic wire up - you have to click on it.

And note VERY close that the button does not see, nor have a event defined IN the markup - but you will see it in the property sheet for that button like this:

[image]

And you can in markup actually force/type in the event define, and intel-sense will do this:

[image]

In fact you MUST DO this if the button is inside of a repeater/gridview/list view etc., since you can't double click on the button in the desinger anyway. So additional information here in regards to if some data repeating type of control is surrounding the button. A button is often part of MUCH markup, and depending on how it is nested, a simple click on the button is not always possible.

So, try typing in the OnClick= (and when you hit "=", you should get intel-sense, and try wire up the button that way.

Comment: I've had a look in designer and the Click property is indeed set to "btnFreshTest_Click".

Comment: It's just this single page, the rest of the application works. After debugging I've found that the page is having errors with a jquery.min file which I'm going to look into and will update the post with what I find.

Comment: start a blank new page. Drop in a button. See that it works.. then start introduction of those external js libraries one by one until it breaks and stops working.